# Service worker events related to web push notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push, push-api

In web push notifications [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en), I see that service worker can get triggered by few events like `push`, `notificationclick`. For tracking CTR, `notificationclick` event is very important. Similarly, is there any event like 'rejectnotification' that gets triggered when user rejects notification. So, service worker can track users rejecting notifications.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that by rejected you mean close? If so there is no such event. There used to be an onclose event but is now deprecated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclose

Answer (score 2):

There is a `notificationclose` event, but only for persistent notifications.

https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#closing-a-notification

Answer (score 0):

There is a `notificationclose` event as described here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/notifications?hl=en